# Android - Convert BMP to JPEG with 8-bit depth

Tags: android, jpeg, bmp, image-formats

I have a fingerprint image which is captured in BMP format. The code is as below.

```
mBitmapFP = Bitmap.createBitmap(wight, height, Config.RGB_565); 
     mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmapFP); 
     mPaint = new Paint(); 

     ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(); 
     cm.setSaturation(0); 
     ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm); 
     mPaint.setColorFilter(f);
```

I have a requirement wherein the BMP file needs to converted to JPEG but with depth of 8-bit. Can someone please help?

Comment: As far as I know (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html), it's not a supported format.

Comment: Is that 8-BPP, as in grayscale or 8-BPP as in color with 8 bits, or 8 bits per component per pixel?